# Wordpress page editor hook?

Tags: wordpress, hook

I am wondering if there is a hook for wordpress that will allow me to edit this portion of the page editor (at the top near the "Add New" button)?

[image: wordpress page editor]

Comment: Not clear what you need to edit ? which portion ?

Comment: I want to add some UI elements to that section (right by the "Add New" button). I want to know if that is possible?

Comment: Do you know what hook I need to use for it?

Comment: Nop, because I have so far no idea of what do you need to add close to the Add New button. Its a drop down menu, a link, an image, a custom text, an input field, echoing some custom code, echoing some wordpress function .... see, perhaps there is no hook but depending in what do you wish to achieve, maybe there is some workaround if there is no hook.

Comment: I am looking to insert a link there that will run some code.

Comment: @jasonaburton looking for the exact same. did you ever find it?

Comment: @Jasonaburton Same here. Know a solution?

Comment: I ended up just using js to put it there.